# How do I create a drop down menu using a button's focus and blur that also apply to it's children

Tags: javascript, html, svelte

I have the following navbar component in svelte that works well enough:

```
<script>
  let selectedTheme = 'dark';
  let isOpen = false;
  const changeTheme = (newTheme) => {
    selectedTheme = newTheme;
    isOpen = false;
  }
</script>

<div>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-container">
      <button 
        on:click={() => isOpen = true}
        
      >
        Theme - {selectedTheme}</button>
      <ul class="dropdown {isOpen ? '' : 'hidden'}">
        <li>
          <button on:click={(e) => {e.stopPropagation(); changeTheme('light')}}>Light</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button on:click={(e) => {e.stopPropagation(); changeTheme('dark')}}>dark</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>{selectedTheme}</p>
</div>
```

When the button is clicked, the dropdown appears and you can change your theme. This is good but what I'd like is if the user clicks anywhere else besides the dropdown, I'd like the dropdown to close.

I thought I could achieve this by using the buttons **focus and blur** properties instead:

```
  <button 
    on:focus={() => isOpen = true}
    on:blur={() => isOpen = false}
  >
    Theme - {selectedTheme}</button>
```

And this does indeed give me the behavior I'd like. If the user clicks the theme button, but then clicks anywhere else on the page, the dropdown menu closes and nothing changes. But it's causing an issue where now the two dropdown menu buttons aren't working. So now the theme cannot be changed.

I've created a minimal [Stackblitz demo to recreate the behavior](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-mpvfcn?file=src%2Fcomponents%2Fnavbar.svelte).

Is there a better way semantically to build this dropdown behavior that is activated on a click and dismissed easily? I'm modeling this off how [MDN theme picker works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

Thank you.

Comment: Using focus/blur is not a good idea. It will not be keyboard accessible; the dropdown on MDN does not do this either. If you try to move focus away from the button to the items in the menu it would close. Menus should toggle on clicking the menu button and close on pressing Escape or clicking outside the menu.

Comment: Also: There should be `role` and aria attributes [as recommended](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/menu-button/).

Comment: @H.B. You're right. I need to go back to the drawing board on this one. Thanks for the link. Those are 3 good demos that I can use as a starting point.

Comment: for this type of problem (where clicking outside an element something should happen) the use of actions is preferred as well.  Search for "Svelte click outside action" for examples.